# Ajax tab control's TabContainer_ActiveTabChanged event is fired on each postback

Tags: ajax, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontrol

I am using Ajax tab control, which includes grids in each tab. The grid have drop down list and button and I want to fire gridview's RowCommand event on button click of gridview Row. But the problem is whenever I click on the button, Tabcontainet_ActiveTabChanged event is fired and grid view is bind again before it fire the RowCommand event.

I can not understand why this event is fired automatically even though I am not firing it intentionally. How can I fire RowCommand event in such cases??
I tried both with update panel and without update panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very strange but TabContainer fires ActiveTabChanged event on each postback if active tab changed or if actual ActiveTabIndex property value equals to 0. I can't find out any reason for such behavior so use solution below on on your own risk. Actually there are two solutions available: the first one is to download AjaxControlToolkit sources, change TabContainer control LoadPostData method and use custom dll :

Actual method:

```
protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
{
    int tabIndex = ActiveTabIndex;
    bool result = base.LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection);
    if (ActiveTabIndex == 0 || tabIndex != ActiveTabIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Just remove `ActiveTabIndex == 0` condition from the code above.

Or you can create your own class inherited from the TabContainer, override that method and use this class instead of the default:

```
namespace AjaxControlToolkit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MyTabContainer
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTabContainer : TabContainer
    {
        protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection)
        {
            int tabIndex = ActiveTabIndex;

            if (SupportsClientState)
            {
                string clientState = postCollection[ClientStateFieldID];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientState))
                {
                    LoadClientState(clientState);
                }
            }

            if (tabIndex != ActiveTabIndex)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using VB.NET:

```
Namespace AjaxControlToolkit
Public Class MyTabContainer
    Inherits TabContainer

    Protected Overrides Function LoadPostData(postDataKey As String, postCollection As NameValueCollection) As Boolean
        Dim tabIndex = ActiveTabIndex

        If SupportsClientState Then
            Dim clientState = postCollection(ClientStateFieldID)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(clientState) Then
                LoadClientState(clientState)
            End If
        End If

        If tabIndex <> ActiveTabIndex Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

Props to Yuriy Rozhovetskiy

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the ActiveTabChanged event fire for no reason.

I fixed it with the below; put this as the first lines in the ActiveTabChanged event.  Change "tabMain" with your actual tab id:

```
        Dim ctrl As Control = Nothing

        'get the event target name and find the control
        Dim ctrlName As String = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName)) Then
            ctrl = Page.FindControl(ctrlName)

            If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
                If ctrl.ID <> "tabMain" Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

If the event came from anywhere but tabMain (in the above example), just get out.

This solved hours of frustration for me!